# pandas: Removing rows from cumulative column after it reaches a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the following dataframe:

```
id1     Val cum_val
3233    24  24
3233    12  36
3233    7   43
3233    6   49
3233    6   55
3233    3   58
3255    5   5
3255    44  49
3255    4   53
3255    8   61
3255    8   69
```

where the cum_val column is cumulative of Val within each group of id1 3233 and 3255.

I want to get the following:

```
id1     Val cum_val
3233    24  24
3233    12  36
3233    7   43
3233    6   49
3233    6   55
3255    5   5
3255    44  49
3255    4   53
```

i.e. keep only the rows until the `cum_val` reaches first value greater than 50. e.g. for id1 = 3255, I have discarded rows with `cum_val` of 61 and 69 as 53 was the first value greater than 50.

I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for shifting values per groups and test for less like `50` for matching also next group after `50`:

```
df = df[df.groupby('id1')['cum_val'].shift(fill_value=0).lt(50)]
print (df)
    id1  Val  cum_val
0  3233   24       24
1  3233   12       36
2  3233    7       43
3  3233    6       49
4  3233    6       55
6  3255    5        5
7  3255   44       49
8  3255    4       53
```